# How to create default Logic Pro sound using EXS24 and .wav file?

Tags: sound-design, logic-pro, sampler

In Logic Pro X, Apple provides many default 'Clap' sounds, like the Atlanta drum kit clap for example. How can I create that same sound by loading a .wav clap into EXS24? What configurations do I need to make?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own kits by opening a new instrument and assigning an audio file to it. Here´s a simple way to do it:

1. In the plugin screen, click the "Edit" button next to the instrument selector
   [image: EXS24]
2. In the instrument editor, click "Zone" and select "Multiple Samples"
   [image: Editor]
3. After choosing your sound file, you can adjust various settings (e.g. if you want to modify loop points, etc.)
4. Save your new instrument by clicking "Instrument" and "Save As". After that, your instrument will show up in the instrument selection menu.